# angularjs ngRepeat orderBy when property key has spaces

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-ng-repeat, angularjs-orderby

I'm getting some data in JSON format which has spaces in the some of the keys:

```
[
    {
        "PlainKey": "SomeValue",
        "Spaced Key": "SomeValue"
    },
    {
        "PlainKey": "SomeValue2",
        "Spaced Key": "SomeValue2"
    }
]
```

This happens at some point:

```
$http.get('https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/80497/htmlTesting/properties/credits.properties' + '?callback=JSON_CALLBACK').then(function (data) {
            $scope.credits = data.data;
        }, function (error) {
            $scope.errorOccured = true;
            console.log("Error:");
            console.log(error);
        });
```

and then `ng-repeat` is used to display it, with ordering:

```
<select ng-model="corder">
  <option value="PlainKey">Plain Key</option>
  <option value="Spaced Key">Spaced Key</option>
</select>

<li ng-repeat="credit in credits | orderBy:corder" >
.....
</li>
```

This doesn't work ( I get an exception )
(The `PlainKey` works because there are no spaces).

I also tried putting the values in `'`:

```
<select ng-model="corder">
  <option value="'PlainKey'">Plain Key</option>
  <option value="'Spaced Key'">Spaced Key</option>
</select>
```

This seems to change the order, but not correctly.

What Am I missing?

Thanks!

Comment: Enclosing `Spaced Key` with single quotes causes `orderBy` to look for an object property with the key `'Spaced Key'`, with the quotes included in the actual property name. Thus, it expects something like `$scope.credits[0]["'Spaced Key'"]` to be accessible. Since this isn't available, that's why you see the inconsistent behaviour.

Comment: @miqid Okay, Thanks. So how would you order by `Spaced Key` in this scenario?

Comment: You could instead supply `orderBy` with a predicate sort function (as opposed to a property name to sort by). Here's a [Plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/Mwe2xu26c1KHeT4KhTDg?p=preview) to demonstrate what I mean.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Comments appeared to help so I'm including it as an answer:

One way to sort items with spaces in their object property names is to pass a predicate sort function into `orderBy` instead of specifying the object property name. The relevant modifications in particular:

**HTML:**

```
<li ng-repeat="credit in credits | orderBy:predicate">
```

**JS:**

```
$scope.predicate = function(val) {
  // $scope.corder corresponds to the object property name to sort by
  return val[$scope.corder];
}
```

Demonstration [Plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/Mwe2xu26c1KHeT4KhTDg?p=preview).

Comment: Whenever I use a predicate like this as a filter and not a function in my controller, I get results that almost seem randomly sorted. Each time it's resorted the order will shuffle.

Answer (score 11):

Simplest way, just surround a field name with UTF8 code for quotation mark:

**HTML**

```
<li ng-repeat="item in items | orderBy:'\u0022Spaced Key\u0022'">
```

**JS**

```
$scope.orderKey = '\u0022Spaced Key\u0022';
```

Comment: Nice! This is the best answer, methinks.